# Detecting acceleration's change frequency with accelerometer

Tags: rotation, accelerometer, frequency

I have an accelerometer with 3 axes and I need to detect acceleration's change frequency. It's ok when object is moving straight, without rotation - in that case I can simply ignore g (acceleration due to gravity), it would have constant direction and won't affect frequency. But what can I do when object is rotating while moving? Is it even possible to (somehow) substract g only with accelerometer, without gyroscope? May be there are some methods of rough calculation, approximation?

Answer (score 0):

The following could work if your accelerometer's gain is the same in all x, y and z directions.

You don't know the orientation of the car so you cannot subtract the gravity from the sensor readings. However, when the car starts moving or there is a sharp break or acceleration then the **length** of the measured acceleration vector changes too.

I would use a low-pass filter to filter out the very high frequency noise that you certainly get in a car. It requires some tweaking and testing but it should not be too difficult.

Of course **it is rather a workaround**, the true solution would be to use gyroscopes. Good luck anyway!